# How to show and then hide a label in javafx after a task is completed

Tags: user-interface, javafx, label

I want to show a label after a button is pressed but after the operations made by the button are finished I want the label to be hidden.

This is what I have tried to do

```
    final Label loadingLabel = new Label();
    loadingLabel.setText("Loading...");
    loadingLabel.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 16));

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setRight(label);
    root.setLeft(button);
    root.setCenter(loadingLabel);
    loadingLabel.setVisible(false);

final Button printButton = new Button("Print part");
    printButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            loadingLabel.setVisible(true);
            //here are some computations
            loadingLabel.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
```

The code doesn't show at all the label.

Comment: Are your computations done on a background thread?

Comment: no, they're done on the same thread

Comment: If they are long working computations, then they will block the `JavaFX Application thread` freezing the UI, resulting in a bad user experience.

Comment: everything takes less than 10 seconds, is it the case that it freezes the UI? What should I do? I don't have a lot of work experience with threads

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how you can use [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) and its [setOnSucceeded()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#setOnSucceeded-javafx.event.EventHandler-) to update the visibility of the labels.

A **service** is used instead of a **Task** because we need to define a reusable Worker object.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SimpleTaskExample extends Application {

    Service service = new ProcessService();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button button = new Button("Press Me to start new Thread");

        Label taskLabel = new Label("Task Running..");
        taskLabel.setVisible(false);
        Label finishLabel = new Label("Task Completed.");
        finishLabel.setVisible(false);

        VBox box = new VBox(20, taskLabel, button, finishLabel);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(box, 200, 200));
        primaryStage.show();

        button.setOnAction(event -> {

            // show the label
            taskLabel.setVisible(true);
            // hide finish label
            finishLabel.setVisible(false);
            // start background computation
            if(!service.isRunning())
                service.start();
        });

        // If task completed successfully, hide the label
        service.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            taskLabel.setVisible(false);
            finishLabel.setVisible(true);
            //reset service
            service.reset();
        });
    }

    class ProcessService extends Service<Void> {

        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {
            return new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    // Computations takes 3 seconds
                    // Calling Thread.sleep instead of random computation
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

You can also use a listener on the `runningProperty()` of the service, if you want to hide the label irrespective whether the task succeeds or fails.

Comment: now the code si made after your model but it still doesn't work. http://pastebin.com/tBdbxRVe

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Are you sure that the Task is finished with `Worker.State as SUCCEEDED` ? If possible ask another question with a link to this question supplying a MCVE.

Comment: the problem is that the label still doesn't appear, else the program runs exactly like before. how do i set the Worker.State as SUCCEEDED? in call i just return null at the end

Comment: What else do you have inside the call method of your Task apart from `return null`? It may be a case that the task is not completed successfully.

Comment: don't have any other returns, but the task completes successfully because after i press the button i see some modification in my table, which are done only if the task completed successfully. Besides this i've seen that the program works only the first time i press the print button. when i press it the second time it doesn't work anymore at all

Comment: the second time i press the button it doesn't call anymore: new Thread(task).start();

Comment: Ahh, I see. Since the Task class defines a one-time object that cannot be reused. You need to use `Service` instead. Please check the updated answer.